# Need Assistance Building an Economic Model

Tags: python, modeling

Fairly new to python, know some basics but want to dive straight in and create economic models, play with the math and interpret the ouputs. However, everytime i place a letter in the equation there will be an error. For example;

```
MoneyDemand = -100+2K
Money Supply = 5000*10K
```

---

```
File "experiment.py", line 20
    MD = -100+2K
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is probably a small issue for most but i need assistance in how to overcome it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've got three `SyntaxError`s here. A `SyntaxError` means that you've written something that isn't valid python. I'd really suggest you look through some python tutorials to get a grip on how to program python. Even something like [learn x in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python/) would probably be helpful.

But in your cases, the fixes are:

1. Ending a number with `k` is not valid python. If by that you mean `1000`, you should just write `2000` or `10000`. (Or, if you want, multiply it by `1000`. See how the error points you at the letter `k` on the line.
2. You can't have spaces in the names of variables. `Money Supply` is not a valid name. Python conventions would probably suggest naming it `money_supply`.

Comment: Thank you, the Money Supply without a space was a typo, but i appreciate the comments and the link you shared.

Answer (score 0):

python does not accept K as an indication of 1000.

You can however using scientific notation.

```
MoneyDemand = -100 + 2e3
MoneySupply = 5000 * 10e3
```

The e can be either lower or upper case.

Also note that I removed a space from your variable name Money Supply -> MoneySupply otherwise you would have a syntax error on the next line.

Comment: Thank you, the Money Supply without a space was a typo, but the e notation really helps.

Comment: glad I could help